# Python3 ERROR With pyowm import OWM produces RequestsDependencyWarning:

Tags: python-requests, python-3.7, urllib3

I recently upgraded to python3.7.3 from python2.7.16 and when I run my weather script I get a *RequestsDependencyWarning* ERROR. I narrowed it down to ***from pyowm import OWM***

```
>>> from pyowm import OWM
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.2) or chardet (2.0.3) doesn't match a supported version!
      RequestsDependencyWarning)
    >>>
```

I have tried the following:

```
~ $ pip uninstall docker-compose
WARNING: Skipping docker-compose as it is not installed.

~ $ pip install chardet
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.0.4)

 ~ $ pip install requests
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (2018.8.24)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)

pip install urllib3
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.26.2)
```

I get the same error when I try *from requests import get*

```
>>> from requests import get
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.2) or chardet (2.0.3) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
>>>
```

Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded chardet:

```
pip install --upgrade chardet

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.0.4)

Collecting chardet
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/chardet/chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
     |................................| 178 kB 409 kB/s
Installing collected packages: chardet
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

elastalert 0.2.4 requires PyYAML>=3.12, which is not installed.
elastalert 0.2.4 requires texttable>=0.8.8, which is not installed.
noaa-sdk 0.1.18 requires requests==2.22.0, but you have requests 2.25.1 which is incompatible.
aiohttp 3.6.2 requires chardet<4.0,>=2.0, but you have chardet 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed chardet-4.0.0
```

I then noticed PyYAML and texttable were missing. After installing those two items I then upgraded chardet:

```
pip install --upgrade chardet

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple

Requirement already satisfied: chardet in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.0.0)
```

Seeing that chardet requirements were met I retried my script and it works fine